# Call Javascript directly from Blazor "HTML" section

Tags: javascript, html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

A .razor component file is defined with a "HTML" section, in which you can define the HTML of your component, and a `@code {}` section in which C# code can be written to add logic to the component.

I know that you can call JS methods from the C# code in the `@code {} section`, but what I cannot find anywhere is if there's any way to call those JS functions from the "HTML" part directly like

```html
<button onclick="a_js_function()">click me</button>
```

as that would be much nicer to write and read.

Alternatively, I'd like to know if it's at all possible to somehow refer to regular HTML with JS from a Blazor PWA. Thanks!

*"why use Blazor then?" -> I don't have a choice :)*

Edit: making globally available JS functions is not desirable either.

### Clarifications

Since I'm seeing much criticism, I'm adding an example of how it could look:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<button @onclick=module.a_js_function>click me<button/>

@code {
    IJSObjectReference module;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
        module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
                "import", "./Pages/Component.razor.js");

    }
}
```

I know that this doesn't work, but since Blazor allows me to call globally available JS *and* write an isolated JS module that is scoped to my component, I was thinking there might be a way to somehow combine both and call scoped JS from the HTML section of the Blazor component.

I think this is a legitimate interrogation, and the fact that it is not possible is not a reason to have it closed.

Comment: Have you tried including JS just like one normally would on an HTML page without Blazor?  See the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72296047/how-to-call-a-javascript-function), where you can see the JS added to an HTML page as usual.  Also, [how JS can interfere with Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71620401/using-js-in-blazor) may be important to consider.

Comment: Yes, you can use javascript - but be aware of the problems devlin has linked to and also be aware that a strict CSP will block inline javascript

Comment: As far as i can tell, the example you linked calls JS in the @code section with C#, thanks for linking those posts though.

Comment: That linked question was to demo how to add JS to HTML because I wasn't clear from your question whether you were asking how to add JS to HTML when using Blazor. You can use normal JS event handlers (as opposed to the in-line JS function call like `onclick`, which I believe is outdated and not the recommended way to use JS these days) from within JS to operate on DOM elements... with the caveats in mind that I posted in the second link.

Comment: You can do what you like in the DOM not managed by the Blazor Renderer, but if you start changing that DOM you will create inconsistences and Dom changes being overridden by Blazor.  Without a Context/User Case to understand what you want to do in `a_js_function` and where the button resides, ....????

Comment: [Polite] I don't have a choice :) is no reason to try and implement it ugly.  Code for the framework.

Comment: thanks for your answers, not need to get all worked up. I'm only making this post because nowhere could I find any info about calling JS from a blazor HTML section. Even if it's impossible I'd like to keep this post as documentation explaining future users that it indeed can't be done.

Comment: @Inspi - Don't worry, I wasn't.   Hypothetical questions are often the hardest to answer - they are just too minimalist.  A bit of context often makes all the difference.

Comment: Am I assuming the js file contains methods which you want to call, rather than running stuff on page load?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis yes, that would be the use case

Comment: @Inspi - I've added an answer similar to that provided by Dimitris.  It's there only to demonstrate a slightly different way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Το call scoped JS from the HTML section of the Blazor component you can do the following:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<button @onclick="@(() => module.InvokeVoidAsync("a_js_function"))">click me</button>

@code {
    IJSObjectReference module;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
                "import", "./Pages/Component.razor.js");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the best we're going to have :) Thanks! I'm resolving this post.

Answer (score 0):

You can call every Javascript normally when it's defined during startup. For Blazor Webassembly this file would be `Index.html` and for Blazor Server it is `_Host.cshtml`

Every function which is included as file or defined here is available within your entire app.

However I strongly recommened doing it the Blazor way. Since it will make future development much easier. It's not a lot of work either.

Inject IJSRuntime. Make an async function and call your Javascript function within.

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<button onclick="a_js_function()">click me</button> 

@code {
  private async Task MyButtonClickAsync()
  {
      await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("a_js_function");
  }
}
}
```

There are a lot of benefits in doing so.

1. You can work with every C# code easily here
2. Debugging the SOftware will be much easier since you can hit the breakpoints from Visual Studio and inspect all values
3. Adding blazor features requires you to use a C# function anyways. You can call C# from Javascript which is IMO much harder than doing it the other way around
4. You can create extension methods for IJSRuntime to call your Javascript function with nice autocompletion, Intellsense and code documentation

Also keep in mind that every Javascript state needs to be managed by yourself

Comment: making globally available javascript is indeed not suitable for my case, I agree that I should not do it. And yes don't worry, I know about the Blazor way of calling JS, but I wanted to find a less verbose alternative or document that it does not exist for future google search.

Comment: How else will `<button onclick="a_js_function()">click me</button>` work if `a_js_function` function is not defined globally?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos - I agree.  The question id too theoretical.

Comment: I don't know myself, but I do know that blazor supports Isolated JS scripts that are only scoped to a component :)

Comment: @Inspi these need to be injected within the component as well and then being called through the `IJSRuntime`

Answer (score 0):

There's an article [here](https://www.meziantou.net/javascript-isolation-in-blazor-components.htm) by Gerald Barre on his blog showing how to do this.  I don't know if he was the original creator or got it from somewhere else.

The code below demonstrates the techniques described in the article.

It's similar to the code in the other answer but only loads the module if it's needed, and disposes it appropriately.

A js file *wwwroot/js/index.js*

```js
export function sayHello(name) {
    alert(`Hello ${name}!`);
}
```

My Index:

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@implements IAsyncDisposable

@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.SayHello>Say Hello</button>

@code {

    private Task<IJSObjectReference>? _module;

    private Task<IJSObjectReference> Module 
        => _module ??= JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/index.js").AsTask();

    private async Task SayHello()
    {
        var module = await this.Module;
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("sayHello", "Blazor");
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (_module != null)
        {
            var module = await _module;
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```